# Map and FlatMap throwing error "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'unknown' in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, collections

I have `data` object which is derived as below. It can have any number of `Array object` each representing count of `ErrorType`.

I am using `Angular9` and writing the below code in `TypeScript`.

```
    const apiResponse = await this.service.geterrors();
    const data = apiResponse ['data'];

data = 
{
  "1": [
    {
      "ErrorType": "Error-1A",
      "Error": "Wrong Password for 1A"
    },
    {
      "ErrorType": "Error-1B",
      "Error": "Host not matching"
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "ErrorType": "Error-2A",
      "Error": "Wrong User for 1A"
    },
    {
      "ErrorType": "Error-2B",
      "Error": "connectivity issue"
    }
  ],
  "3": [
    {
      "ErrorType": "Error-3A",
      "Error": "Wrong version"
    }
  ],
  "16": [
    {
      "ErrorType": "Error-4A",
      "Error": "Unknown"
    }
  ]
  ...
  ... 
}
```

I want to capture all the count values and push them in an array `counts` in descending order.

```
counts = [16, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1];
```

I want to capture the corresponding `ErrorType` and push them in an array `errorTypes`.

```
errorTypes = ['Error-4A', 'Error-3A', 'Error-2B', 'Error-2A', 'Error-1B', 'Error-1A'];
```

I have written the following code so far but it is throwing errors:

```
const errs = Object.entries(data).map(([k, v]) => 
    [v.map(() => +k), v.map(e => e.ErrorType).reverse()]
  )
  .sort((a, b) => b[0][0] - a[0][0])
;
const [counts, errorTypes] = errs[0]
  .map((_, i) => errs.flatMap((_, j) => errs[j][i]))
;

console.log(counts, errorTypes);
```

The above code is throwing 2 errors:

- `TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'unknown'.`

  `TS2339: Property 'flatMap' does not exist on type 'any[][]'.`

Comment: I'm confused about how these are categorized.  Do we want the total type for `1` errors including `Error-1A` and `Error-1B`, or are those treated separately?

Comment: those are treated separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is throwing errors because typescript isn't sure if it has an array of numbers or an array of strings and it can't map on that union.

This is more verbose than what you wrote, but I can't wrap my head around what your code is actually doing so I just rewrote it.  It turns out I didn't need any advanced typescript stuff with this approach, though I did define types for our data structures.

```
interface TypedError {
    ErrorType: string;
    Error: string;
}

const data: Record<number, TypedError[]> = 
{...}
```

I put the errors into a record keyed by `ErrorType` which contains the `ErrorType`, `count`, and number of the `group`.  Then I sort this by comparing the `count` properties of the elements.

```
interface ErrorCount {
    count: number;
    ErrorType: string;
    group: number;
}

const keyedCounts: Record<string, ErrorCount> = {};

Object.entries(data).forEach(
    ([num, arr]) => arr.forEach(
        ({ErrorType}) => keyedCounts[ErrorType] = {
            count: ( keyedCounts[ErrorType]?.count || 0 ) + 1,
            group: parseInt(num),
            ErrorType,
        }
    )
);

const sorted = Object.values(keyedCounts);
sorted.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count)
```

From there, you can extract your arrays

```
const counts = sorted.map( o => o.count );
const names = sorted.map( o => o.ErrorType );
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOEAmBRKKAeymQG8BYAKGVuQOKg2wC5kBnMKUAcwG5qdeoRJtO3EP2oBfatQREQnZDjhg4bAEoQFUHAB4QAVwC2AI2gAaNFlwMSAbQC6APmQBeZNUo1kAIgBGPzYHQTofIVo-eyZbYP8YgFoAgEE-SzChaJEoeL8AdWJJZAAFOHZ2AHcSHGQYEmRUv0zkaQzfWgjI7MZmCDykgIAhdJaomLyACSJlECIwZBM1BAALXmaO1rCndqiAJnjQza6smL6BnMS9tN3uibYCop5kAFV2aDqGppa2lpO6Hokc4PJJ7Ea3U45PIKEAgHRgYAAN2AYHQyGAFSM-R+21ufgAzIc-mMEjlgaTGIl8TcSYDcg9CopnojoOxgIoNkJZL4dmFAgA2InHWlnOIgy4AFhpm3GUIeLxAAGs5pUQJy6L9hTKKUCxTqoIkpaNtXS8grlURVeraJqhP9Zb09XTDdLIvqzUqVWqcTyZHIqKBILBECgYgBhIhGcDkFoKKNgNjGczQASbUWsDhcXipoQ8YhGTCJ0wWKCp7nyRTKRUQdC4CPx9haHQ1fTiXjWcOR8BuTxkaSp6gAeTMACt4QA6CDgbgQdgAClU6gAlOP6lA8IgVnOWnOHEnrHBCE4lx43IeoKuSBvVtvtbQ52R0xBpCf3G5q7WcPXwOwHE+nB4MZ3pEcbgGwc7IB+dZdmAv7-gA-OOoELAAPihyAAAzICeADUjQQm6dB5pGhbIJgh7vAAkuAc5JkuBGEcIjrYAxGotEu1BLgOVAwso7AkJAtSeMOY4IGA46InAAA2WLzlBX4wewXHUPxUCCeOqlgHOc5wNYZivm4ZhITByCJMgcDGfGHFUBWSgLMh7CAZpuDjksmAQUQp7IEQlnRspPGVgsIBwCYs5OQJLluR5Xk+U+2HcbxRBSRA45SUQPAPg51jBaF7DWM5OAvnwQA)